# PHP alternative for preg_replace()?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ascii

I have a long string with several special characters, specifically quotes (", ') and greater, less than brackets.. (<, >) and it's messing up my HTML.

I was wondering if there was a simple way to replace all occurrences of these with their ascii equivalents (&gt; , &lt; , etc) before I spend a bunch of time writing my own function. I'm terrible at RegEx :/

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [`htmlentities()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp) and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp) available, depending on what you exactly need. If you only want to break `,`, `<` and `>`, you can do

```
$new_str = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Comment: Beautiful. entities was what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

This function will replace all html characters with their html entity equivalents.

Ex:

```
<?php
$before="<code>";
$after=htmlspecialchars($before);
echo $after; //&lt;code&gt;
?>
```

Be sure to use ENT_QUOTES as the second argument if you want to also replace single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's str_replace function. Check the php manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php.

```
$text = str_replace('<', '', $text);
```

This code removes the less than sign from $text by replacing it with an empty string.

I would strongly recommend you explore the regex approach using preg_replace(), though. It's faster and much more powerful.

Comment: preg_replace is never faster than str_replace for single key/value replacements.

Comment: You are correct, but it sounds like the asker will be replacing a whole bunch of characters.

Comment: Oops, looks like I read the question wrong. I thought you were removing the characters. The functions htmlspecialchars or htmlentities are the way to go for replacing chars with HTML equivalents, unless you run into characters these functions don't support. Then use str_replace.